# How to clear the content of an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How do I clear the content of my IFRAME element, using javascript, without loading a blank page into it?

I can figure out to do this: `iframe_element.src = "blank.html"`, but there must be a better, instant, method.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
about:blank
```

is a "URL" that is blank. It's always clear

You can set the page's source to that, and it will clear.

Comment: iframe_element.src = "about:blank"

Comment: doing document.getElementByid("frame_name").src = about:blank caused the app to open a new blank page/tab when src = about:blank

Comment: @zee yes, but you can use document.querySelector(".frame_name").contentWindow.location.replace(`about:blank`); and works like a charm!

Comment: This was my first thought too, but this method doesn't work if the src is already about:blank, if it is then this method does nothing.
In my case I've posted into the iframe so the src stayed about:blank. See the second most upvoted solution, that works in my case too.

Comment: @soger If your src is already `about:blank`, then why isn't it blank? Have you been programmatically updating the DOM? If so, you probably already know how to programmatically clear the DOM? Either way, what might be happening is a browser non-reload, which you can override by pointing to `about:blank?guid=01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef` or other methods.

Comment: @McKay No, as I've said before I did a post with target as the iframe, but the post takes a few seconds (large image manipulation) so I wanted to clear the iframe when the user presses the submit button the second time. I already did the document.open(), thing I didn't realize you can add parameters to about:blank, I usually add the current timestamp in similar cases, that's easier to generate.

Answer (score 20):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");
var html = "";

iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

tested in IE, Firefox and Chrome ... it did it :)

Comment: Simple... best approach in my opinion.  I'm not using an iframe with a src attribute and so I'd rather not add a src attribute of "about:blank".  I'm loading and clearing my iframe based on HTML data saved in a variable and so this was absolutely perfect.

Comment: Just fyi, this doesn't clear JS global scope.

Answer (score 8):

Your technique is the most robust.  Its the one I use myself.  At times content may be delivered over HTTPS and the use of about:blank can cause warning messages to appear to the effect of "do you want to include content from unsecure location" or some such thing.

Something being instant is a matter of perception however if you have a single Blank.html file on your site configured with a long cache expiry the client will only ever fetch the page once (at the most once per-session).

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do this :

```
var iframe_element = window.frames['iframe_name'];
iframe_element.document.open();
iframe_element.document.close();
```

Comment: You can also write to the document while it is open, if you want to add a basic message (or what ever) to the window.

Answer (score 2):

I have had difficulties with "about:blank" on pages with many IFrames. It does not seem to be a valid location in every browser (I never found out for sure, though). Anyway, I am happy with `javascript:void(0);`

Comment: what happens if Javascript is disabled?

Comment: He is specifically asking how to reset a IFrame location after Javascript. While I imagine that javascript: urls gracefully downgrade, I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var doc = null;
    window.onload = function() {
        alert("Filling IFrame");
        doc = document.getElementById("test");

        if( doc.document ) {
            document.test.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>"; //Chrome, IE
        }else {
            doc.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>"; //FireFox
        }

            setTimeout(function() { 
                alert("Clearing IFrame");

                if( doc.document ) {
                    document.test.document.body.innerHTML = ""; //Chrome, IE
                }else {
                    doc.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = ""; //FireFox
                }

            }, 1000);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="test" name="test">

    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

// First I get the window from its Id.

```
var my_content = document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow.document;
```

// Then I clear it by setting the body tag inner HTML to an empty string.

```
my_content.body.innerHTML="";
```

// Now when I write my new content it does not get appended to the end of the body and the iframe body will contain only fresh content.

```
my_content.write(new_content);
```

Comment: Just a note for others who are scanning for answers:  This does not work if you have an applications with multiple iframes... some of which are not visible.  Removing the `src` attribute does work though.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.removeAttribute('srcdoc');
```

Work in Chrome

Comment: Im afraid this does not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Just get the Iframe and remove the documentElement from it. The Iframe will be blank

```
 var frame = document.getElementById("YourFrameId"),
 frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
 frameDoc.removeChild(frameDoc.documentElement);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{
    var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

    //Do whatever you need with the content    
}
```

Answer (score -4):

$("#iframe").contents().find("body").html('');

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: You would also only be able to modify the contents of an iframe if it was originally loaded from the same domain as the containing page.

Comment: @PeterL. Although I agree that this answer is too terse to be useful, it does, technically, answer the OP, since `jQuery` _is_ `JavaScript`.