# Javascript function replace instead of write

Tags: javascript, html

```
function sethtml(a,b)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("canvas_html").contentDocument; x.write(b);
}
```

This works but I want to replace the content instead of writing to it.

Comment: Is `x` supposed to be an iframe? More detail is needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.innerHTML = b;
```

This will replace entirely the contents of `x` for ordinary DOM elements. In the case of an iframe, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785040/how-to-clear-the-content-of-an-iframe) for details on how to clear an iframe. You could then simply use the `write` method to add your new content.

Comment: Ended up with `function sethtml(a,b)
{
    var doc = document.getElementById("canvas_html");
                    if( doc.document ) {
                    document.test.document.body.innerHTML = ""; //Chrome, IE
                }else {
                    doc.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = ""; //FireFox
                }

doc.contentDocument.write(b);
}`