# Lazy Load iFrame Inside the Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, lazy-loading

wanna ask about how to lazy load the iFrame inside the Tab every time the tab is clicked? And I want to add an active class at the first time it loads. I don't understand how to code, i'm very new here.

Mine is like this :

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <iframe class= "tab-content" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" loading="lazy">
    </iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <iframe class= "tab-content" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" loading="lazy">
    </iframe> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <iframe class= "tab-content" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy">
    </iframe> 
  </div>
</body>
```

Please help me how to solve this. I currently using wordpress so, is it possible doing this in wordpress? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, it is. But how to reload the not active class to be active every time i click on it?? I think that it's just after reloading the page, the not active class i click is loading the page not everytime i click will be loading the page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785040/how-to-clear-the-content-of-an-iframe  You'll need to clear the content from the iFrames that are not in the foreground in the openCity function to prevent any active content from running in the background.

Comment: Can you give me an example code please? I don't understand

Comment: Sure, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the iFrames in the background to be "unloaded" you need to remove the content from them, which can be done by removing the `src=` attribute.  I added a loop at the top of your function that iterates through all of the `<iframe>` elements and "clears" them, then... only the iframe that is visible will load because all of the iframes are already set to `loading="lazy"`  This could be refactored and written way better, but this example keeps your existing code and accomplishes the goal.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, iframes;
  
  iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].removeAttribute('src');
    if (i == 0) { iframes[i].setAttribute('src', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London' ); }
    if (i == 1) { iframes[i].setAttribute('src', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris' ); }
    if (i == 2) { iframes[i].setAttribute('src', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo' ); }
  }
  
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Scenario:  Let say you click the "London" button and then you click the "Paris" button and then inspect the source.  Both London and Tokyo `<iframe>` content will be blank because London has been "cleared" and Tokyo was never accessed, while Paris is visible.

[image: Scenario - Inspect Source]

https://jsfiddle.net/ard45tL2/5/

You could clean it up a little bit by keeping the `src` content in a separate data attribute like `data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London"` and then simply copying from there after removing the `src` attribute and setting it back.  Just an idea.

```html
<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <iframe class= "tab-content" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" loading="lazy">
    </iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <iframe class= "tab-content" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" loading="lazy">
    </iframe> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <iframe class= "tab-content" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy">
    </iframe> 
  </div>
</body>
```

By adding the `data-src` attribute above you could simplify the loop.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, iframes;
  
  iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].removeAttribute('src');
    iframes[i].setAttribute('src', iframes[i].getAttribute('data-src') );
  }
  
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ard45tL2/6/

Finally, I split up the `iframe.removeAttribute()` and `iframe.setAttribute()` functions into their respective loops to combine it with your existing code.

- As you are setting `"display = none"` I set `iframe.removeAttribute()`
- As you are setting a particular city to `active` I set the `iframe.setAttribute()`

This is probably best because it doesn't even set the source of the `<iframe>` elements that aren't visible.

[image: src Attribute removed]

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, iframe;
   
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    iframe = tabcontent[i].firstElementChild;  //Added
    iframe.removeAttribute('src');             //Added
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  iframe = document.getElementById(cityName).firstElementChild;   //Added
  iframe.setAttribute('src', iframe.getAttribute('data-src') );   //Added
  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ard45tL2/7/